# Syntax for include files in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, interface

I want to organize interface aliases (for example `eth0:1`) in separate files (`/etc/network/conf.d/eth0_1.cnf`).

Anyone know the syntax to load this external file from `/etc/network/interfaces`, or where I can find it?  I do not want the interface to start automatically.

I've had a look at `man interfaces(8)` without any luck.  But I have seen this done before, and know it's possible.

I tried `load /etc/network/conf.d/eth0_1.cnf` and `include /etc/network/conf.d/eth0_1.cnf` directives, no dice.

OS is ubuntu 11.  Any ideas are really appreciated.

Edit: Thanks.  When I saw this done before it was on centos/rh.

Edit: `source` looks promising but I can't seem to get it going.  When I put:

`source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.conf`

at the top of

`/etc/network/interfaces`

I get the error: `/etc/network/interfaces:3: misplaced option`

So maybe this didn't get included in Ubuntu 11.04? Where did you see that it was included there?

Comment: The magic word is `source`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

from `man 5 interfaces` KNOWN BUGS/LIMITATIONS section:

> It is not currently possible to divide up /etc/network/interfaces into multiple files.  A feature that would make this possible is  some  sort  of inclusion directive.  No such feature exists in the current ifupdown program.  For more information see Debian [bug #159884](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=159884).

**UPDATE:**

Since ubuntu [11.10](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/interfaces.5.html):

> Lines beginning with "**source**" are used to include  stanzas  from  other files, so configuration can be split into many files. The word "source" is followed by the path of file to be sourced. Shell wildcards  can  be used.  (See wordexp(3) for details.)

So the syntax is:

```
source path/to/configfile
```